# Some PDFs uploaded to AWS S3 bucket have incorrect Content-Type metadata; won't open in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Media Cloud, which allows me to upload files into my CMS, which pass through to an S3 bucket. I'm not sure whether this is happening at the plugin level or the S3 level, but sometimes, when the PDF arrives in my bucket, the metadata shows the Content-Type as image/png, and not application/pdf.

This means that the PDF won't open in a browser, because the browser is trying to treat it as an image. Does anyone know why this might happen, and if there is a rule I can set to force all pdfs to have the PDF metadata?

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Upload an offending PDF direct to S3 and see what the resulting content type metadata is. That will likely tell you whether it's S3 or the plugin.

Comment: @OARP I was using 4.3.11, but just upgraded to 4.4.0. Good suggestion to upgrade.

Comment: @jarmod, I have tried this and can't reproduce the problem with a direct upload, but the problem is sporadic in general, so I can't rule out that it's AWS.